# How to solve append after update?

Tags: python, pandas

I updated pyton pandas and now append is not working.

```
for row in lista_dist:
    for col in row:
        if col > 100:
            a = col
        else:
            df_dist = df_dist.append({'Conc': a, 'Num': col}, ignore_index=True)
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The append feature was replaced by pd.concat. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html
It takes a list of dataframes and merges them into one.

The new code could look like this:

```py
df_list = list() # store all new created df in a list
for row in lista_dist:
    for col in row:
        if col > 100:
            a = col
        else:
            # create df from dict and add to list
            df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Conc': a, 'Num': col}))
# merge list
df_dist = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly not working, df_dist = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True) sintax error

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bracket. Dos it work now?

Comment: Not yet! line 302, in calcula_dist_incid_oficial
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Conc': a, 'Num': col}))    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: This sounds like df_list is a DataFrame. It should be a list though, as the first line in my example declares. I probably named in a bit weird, but there is a difference between  `df_list` and `df_dist`! Make sure you don't mix these two! Also check your indentation, that could be an issue as well.

Answer (score -1):

I solved using this code

```py
df_list = []
for row in lista_dist:
    for col in row:
        if col > 100:
            a = col
        else:
            df_list.append([a,col])

df_dist = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=["Conc","Num"])
```